# Alternatives for data entry k* in index k

Tags: database, indexing

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this concept of Alternative 1 vs 2/3 for data entry into an index. Here is an excerpt from some notes:

> Alternative 1:
> Actual data record (with key
> value k)
> – If this is used, index structure is a file
> organization for data records (like Heap
> files or sorted files).
> – At most one index on a given collection of
> data records can use Alternative 1.
> – This alternative saves pointer lookups but
> can be expensive to maintain with
> insertions and deletions.

> Alternative 2: (k, rid of matching data record) and
> Alternative 3: (k, list of rids of matching data records)
> – Easier to maintain than Alt 1.
> – If more than one index is required on a given file, at most
> one index can use Alternative 1; rest must use Alternatives 2
> or 3.
> – Alternative 3 more compact than Alternative 2, but leads to
> variable sized data entries even if search keys are of fixed
> length.
> – Even worse, for large rid lists the data entry would have to
> span multiple blocks!

Can someone help me understand this by providing some concrete examples?